# cron @reboot ubuntu ldap dependency

Tags: cron, users, upstart

Question: Users can configure cronjobs `@reboot`, but the cron environment is not ready for users at boot time. How can cron be forced to run only after the system is ready for users on Ubuntu?

On a Ubuntu 19.04 server I created the following cronjob:

```
crontab -l
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start -c /usr/local/bin/node /home/username/subdirectory/someservice.js
```

After reboot the syslog says:

```
Jul 26 16:30:06 METIS systemd[1]: cron.service: Succeeded.
Jul 26 16:31:59 METIS cron[1287]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jul 26 16:31:59 METIS cron[1287]: (username) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
```

My system (METIS) is using ldap which works without problems for normal use but when used with `cron @reboot` it cannot find the user, probably because ldap or the network is not yet started when cron is executing the @reboot command.

I found a [patch for debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767016) which changes the cron.init file. Although Ubuntu and Debian are related, I cannot find a cron.init file on Ubuntu 19.04

On Ubuntu, can cron be forced to run AFTER the system has been set up to work for all users? How?

Comment: You can not. . If you need that that is done in /etc/profile or bashrc or startup applications or as a logical construct in a service

Comment: I wrote "user environment". I did not mean the bash env, but the system configuration that users normally have available (running network, working ldap logins) when executing commands

Comment: Again: no. You  need any of the locations I me tioned. Systemd logica seems the most obvious

Comment: if I replace ```@reboot``` by ```*/5 * * * *```, the command properly executes every 5 minutes, not requiring any change to /etc/profile or bashrc. So the problem really is a matter of timing @reboot, or not?

Comment: yes and no. cron does not understand the concept of relations unless you code it in your script. your option is a waste of cycles. systemd understands the "start this when this is ready". Seems like a far better approach. systemd scripts are easy to make (a template is easy to find on google). Plus systemd can do automatic error catching for you (and respawn).